# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to listt

Tags: python, concatenation

Dear Python Professionals, please help as the code mentioned below:

```
klci = ['1015', '6399', '6888', '4162', '1023', '6947', '3034']
klse = '.KL'
tickers = klci + klse

print(tickers)
```

My expected result is:

```
['1015.KL', '6399.KL', '6888.KL', '4162.KL', '1023.KL', '6947.KL', '3034.KL']
```

Comment: `tickers = [x + klse for x in klci]`. You cannot code without doing **any** reading. So do some.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis there is a nicer way of putting that. And for the question in hand, the idea is that you have to add each element together separately, in a loop.

Comment: The question to the OP would be: "Where did you get the information that it would work like this?". If it's from the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) we might suggest a better explanation there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
klci = ['1015', '6399', '6888', '4162', '1023', '6947', '3034']
klse = '.KL'
tickers = [x + klse for x in klci]

print(tickers)
```

**output:**

```
['1015.KL', '6399.KL', '6888.KL', '4162.KL', '1023.KL', '6947.KL', '3034.KL']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Professionals. But, if it's my code

```
klci = ['1015', '6399', '6888', '4162', '1023', '6947', '3034']
klse = '.KL'
for ele in range(len(klci)):
   klci[ele] += klse
tickers = klci
print(tickers)
```

It's work well :D

Comment: nice try! But not, that juggling with `index`es like that is an error-prone way of doing things. Using Python one can write much more elegant code. Take a look at what the standard way of looping through `list`s is (`enumerate`, aso..)

Comment: why do you need `range(len(klci))`  ? why you calling them unnecessarily ??

Comment: Thank for commenting. I just start learning for python, I gonna trying hard work for my coding skill !